# Hibernate get record by property won't work

Tags: java, database, hibernate

First post here so I'm sorry if I don't format right and cause other problems :D. Please have mercy.
So we're learning the very basics of hibernate in University and are asked to do the mapping and sql-ish methods of the commandline interface on our own. We were given transient methods and had to edit them to make'em persistent. 
Now the commandline interface asks you to put in the login and password of any estateagent and will return some string if you fail (wrong password to username) and let you enter a deeper level of the interface if you enter correct username and password. Note that the university provided the code for the commandlineInterface, therefore I assume its correct. Also I tested the transient version which worked.

This method seems to be the flawed one but I don't know why

```
public EstateAgent getEstateAgentByLogin(String login) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;

    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        EstateAgent p = (EstateAgent) session.get(EstateAgent.class, login);
        tx.commit();
        return p;
    }catch(HibernateException e){
        if(tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        session.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I also have a method to add an EstateAgent into the database.

```
public void addEstateAgent(EstateAgent ea) {
    //estateAgents.add(ea); transient
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        EstateAgent estateagent = ea;
        session.save(estateagent);
        tx.commit();
    } catch(HibernateException e){
        if(tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   finally{
        session.close();
    }
}
```

But I can tell adding EstateAgents works because after executing

```
public void addTestData() {
    EstateAgent m = new EstateAgent();
    m.setName("Gary Oak");
    m.setAddress("test");
    m.setLogin("gary");
    m.setPassword("oak");
    this.addEstateAgent(m);
    }
```

Its Hibernate 3.0 afaik

[Hibernate for EstateAgent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJCSM.png)

and for the Entity Class

```
 package de.dis2018.data;

 import java.util.Set;

 import de.dis2018.util.Helper;


public class EstateAgent {
private int id;
private String name;
private String address;
private String login;
private String password;
static int currentId = 0;
private Set<Estate> estates;

public EstateAgent() {
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Set<Estate> getEstates() {
    return estates;
}

public void setEstates(Set<Estate> estates) {
    this.estates = estates;
}

public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;

    result = prime * result + ((getName() == null) ? 0 : getName().hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((getAddress() == null) ? 0 : getAddress().hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((getLogin() == null) ? 0 : getLogin().hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((getPassword() == null) ? 0 : getPassword().hashCode());

    return result;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;

    if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof EstateAgent))
        return false;

    EstateAgent other = (EstateAgent)obj;

    if(other.getId() != getId() ||
            !Helper.compareObjects(getName(), other.getName()) ||
            !Helper.compareObjects(getAddress(), other.getAddress()) ||
            !Helper.compareObjects(getLogin(), other.getLogin()) ||
            !Helper.compareObjects(getPassword(), other.getPassword()))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

I can see the record in the database. (this method is executed everytime you start the java application after dropping and creating the tables)
Any Idea where I'm wrong? Please tell me if you need more info

Comment: How does the EstateAgent entity and database table looks like? Which version of hibernate do you use?

Comment: Edited the question, hope thats the information you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EstateAgent p = (EstateAgent) session.get(EstateAgent.class, login);
```

Session's get method returns you entity of class from the first parameter with the id from the second. As I can see you have an id field, but login is not the one. To get a record with some property you should look for Criteria API(but I don't like to use it for such simple queries) or just write it in JPQL.

`(EstateAgent) session.createQuery("SELECT ea FROM EstateAgent WHERE ea.login:=login").setParameter("login", login).getSingleResult();`

I think this will do the job.Remember that `getSingleResult()` method will throw exceptions if there's 0 or more than one record with such login.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using Criteria but the error was in the code given by universty.

Comment: Note it's the hibernate API, it's HQL, not JPQL (which is the query language of the Java Persistence API, JPA, and a subset of HQL)

Comment: The criteria API is considered to be deprecated since hibernate 5.2. It's recommended to use JPA.